# Monitoring file changes for larger files in java

Tags: java, file, monitoring, teamspeak

I'm currently looking for a good method to monitor file changes.

Situation:
I've a Teamspeak3 Server running, which ofc creates .log files. One each startup. Parallely there is a java bot running, using the server query api.

Unfortunatly, the query api for teamspeak is very restricted if it comes to catching important events (like server group assignments etc). Those are catched and logged by the server, but not fired to the query client.

My idea is to monitor the server's *.log file, reacting to file changes and resolving the actual event by the newest file entry.

My issue is, that I've to read-in the whole file every time a change has been noticed. I mean, those files reach 10mb++ easily and depending on the ts3 server's "population", changes happen frequently.

Monitoring the file (or the dir, to be precise) is easy using java.nio.file,
but how do I read only the last line?

I can't really think of an elegant way to handle this right now.

Grateful for help and advice!

Xida

Comment: Can you call `tail -n 1` using Process API?

Answer (score 0):

You could use commons-io ReversedLinesFileReader in combination with the WatchService API. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReversedLinesFileReader.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Depending on the frequency of these events this may not be the most performant. It could also be flaky with missing events.  You'd have to keep track of which events you've already processed.  It may be a better option to tail a log file, and process the input that way from StandardIn.